# Clear Most Significant Bit of two bytes

Tags: binary, hex, bit

Let's say I have this HEX value:

3FFF

The problem states that I have to divide this into two bytes like so:
0011 1111    and     1111 1111

Then I have to Clear the Most Significant Bit (MSB) in each byte, from what I understand I have to change the left-most bit to Zero like so:

0011 1111    and 0111 1111
which in HEX is:
3F 7F

However the problem states that the Expected Result should be:
7F 7F

Am I missing something? I wonder if the expected result is wrong or I'm missing something that I should be doing when clearing the MSB bit in each byte.

Comment: Clearing a bit in an unsigned value will never increase the value, so it looks like the "Expected Result" is wrong.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one... Though this is completely language-agnostic so perhaps tagging neither would be better

Comment: Better ask whoever assigned this question for clarification or errata.

Comment: I suspect that the question asked was to divide a single 14-bit value into two 7-bit values.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You're right, I forgot that, I added an Image PROBLEM TO SOLVE

Comment: Unless you immediately remove this image, and replace it with the text version, your question will be downvoted. There is no reason, whatsoever, for purely-programming questions on stackoverflow.com to have bloated, unsearchable images as part of them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Removed the image and replaced with text version.

Comment: Great, now you can answer your own question. Step 1: mask out the lowest seven bits from the original value. Step 2: shift and mask out the upper seven bits from the original value. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

**The "expected result" is wrong.**

It is impossible to get a *higher* value by clearing a bit.<sup>†</sup>

I didn't validate your own suggested result, but on the surface it looks logical to me.

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> inb4 pedants pointing out two's complement's sign bit; go away plz!</sub>

Comment: @James I inb4'd you bro

Comment: @James: I find nuclear devices make racing in orbit more dangerous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit he can do it by dividing the byte then into tow nibbles then masking

Comment: @Raindrop7: He's not asking how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

use masks and logic operations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    unsigned char a = 255; // 11111111 // consider your variable is 255
    unsigned char LowNibble, HiNibble, tmp = a; // self-explanatory
    tmp <<= 4; // discard the high nibble
    tmp >>= 4; // storing the low nibble in tmp

    LowNibble = tmp; // assigning low nibble to LowNibble
    tmp = a;  // again for Hi nibble

    HiNibble = tmp >> 4; // discard low nibble and storing high nibble in HiNibble


    cout << "LowNibble: " << (int)LowNibble << endl; // just for checking
    cout << "HiNibble: "  << (int)HiNibble << endl;

    unsigned char mask = 119;   // 01110111 // you said discard the low nibble's highest bit and the high nibble's highest bit so we make a mask of 1s only clear the forth bit of each nibble which is produces in decimal 119 

    unsigned conc = HiNibble << 4; // assign high nibble to conc
    conc |= LowNibble; //putting low nibble in the first bits of con

    // now con contains both high and low nibbles
    conc &= mask; // clear the highest bit of both two nibbles

    cout << (int)conc << endl; //checking

   // now dividing again the byte to get what you wanted two nibbles with highest bit cleared:

    tmp = conc;
    tmp <<= 4;
    tmp >>= 4;

    LowNibble = tmp;
    tmp = conc;

    HiNibble = tmp >> 4;

    cout << "LowNibble: " << (int)LowNibble << endl;
    cout << "HiNibble: "  << (int)HiNibble << endl;


    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?